# What options does a judge have to control an unruly defendant?

Tags: rules-of-court

If a defendant is unable or unwilling to control himself (in terms of interrupting procedure), what options does a judge have besides physically gagging or taping the mouth shut?

## Clarification via Context

https://www.cnn.com/2018/08/03/us/cleveland-judge-mans-mouth-taped-shut-trnd/index.html

Comment: US? Fines, possibly toss in jail, stop the proceedings...

Comment: What kind of trial? Unless the person is being physical they won't restrain them. They also will not gag/tape a persons mouth shut. If they are spitting they may earn a ["spit hood"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spit_hood). Depending on the type of trial the judge may order jail time, contempt of court or just find in favor of the opposing side (more with civil/small claims suits). If that side is represented they may ask for the individual to be ordered out of the court. If you can clarify the type of trial you are asking about, and jurisdiction, that would help for an actual answer.

Comment: Both comments are accurate. I would only add that in the unlikely event that the defendant is *pro se* (which means that no attorney represents him or her), the court could prohibit that party to continue representing himself. The court would make that ruling [supposedly] only if the pattern of disruptions encompass multiple hearing dates.